# pkill -f vlc not killing /usr/bin/vlc --started-from-file file:///home/pi/hdd/DL/

Tags: kill

I have a vlc that doesnt want to stop running, even after closing it.

When I run

```
ps aux
```

, I get:

```
pi       31284  0.8  2.1 288520 84592 ?        Sl   20:10   0:05 /usr/bin/vlc --started-from-file file:///home/pi/hdd/DL/Explanation%20of%20Jodan%20Part%201.mp4
```

but when I try to kill it with:

```
pkill -f vlc
```

but it doesnt work. Why ?

Answer (score 1):

To find Process ID of the vlc , Run

```
ps -e | grep -i VLC
```

It will list the process ID of VLC as

```
46577 ?        00:00:58 vlc
```

Now to kill it , use

```
sudo kill -9 46577
```